# Throw exception if the file does not exist in constructor and try/catch it when creating an object in main(), if good - start using the object

Tags: c++, exception

I want to open a file in my constructor and read data from it. The check if the file can be opened should be in the constructor (from my point of view) and if there is an exception - throw it and try/catch it in the main, when I try to initialize a new object. But if an exception appears I want to continue asking the user for another try to enter the filename. I've came up with something like this:

```
fstream fp;

class myClass {
    myClass(const string& n) {
        //try to open a file and read data from it to write it in a list
        fp.open (n, ios::in);
        if (!fp) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Could not open file");
        }
        //use fp to read data and put the data in a list
    }
};

void main () {
    cout << "Please enter input file name: \n";
    string iname = "";
    cin >> iname;
    ifstream ist{iname};
    try {
        myClass obj(iname);
    } catch (std::exception &ex) {
        std::cout << "Ouch! That hurts, because: "
            << ex.what() << "!\n";
    }
    /* if the file is not found or can't be opened for some reason, get back to the 'cin >> iname;' part
       else - just start using obj to do something with it */
}
```

At the moment the code I've came up with only throws an exception if the entered file name can't be opened and the program ends.

I want the user to be able to enter file name and try create an object with the specified file name. If the file cannot be opened - exception should be thrown in the constructor of the object and he should then be able to enter a new file name. Is it possible to throw an exception in the constructor of the object and catch it in main with a try/catch block only on the object initialization? If no exceptions are thrown, the code after the try/catch block should continue and you could start using the successfully created object?

Comment: Aaaaaand what's your question ?

Comment: It's not necessary to write `string iname = "";` you can just say `string iname;` to create an empty string. Why are you creating `fstream ist` with an empty filename? [Why aren't you checking the read from `cin`?](http://kayari.org/cxx/antipatterns.html#istream-check) Why is `fp` a global variable? You can't "just start using obj" because it's not in scope outside the try-catch block.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, good points. How can I initialize `obj` in such way that it will be visible to the rest of the main function? And my question is, how to put the user input of a correct filename in a loop, with the the try/catch block as well?

Comment: @Thomas, well my question is how can I put the user input (enter filename) in a loop, such as if the user enters a wrong filename or the file can't be opened, an exception is thrown and he can try entering a new filename or something similiar?

Comment: Yes, the way to do something in a loop is to use a loop. Also, `main` must return `int` not `void`

Comment: @Thomas, well how do I write a proper while loop that checks if the object can be created with the specified file name. If good - start using the object, if bad - throw exception and enter new file name?

Comment: Don't use the loop to check "if the object can be created with the specified file name", just use the loop to restart the whole thing if an exception happens. If there's no exception, break out of the loop after everything works ok: `while (true) { try { /* create the object and use it */ ; break; } catch (...) { /*handle exception */ } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a loop!

```
  int main () {
    bool done = false;
    cout << "Please enter input file name: \n";
    string iname;
    while (!done && cin >> iname) {
      try {
        myClass obj(iname);
        // use obj ...

        done = true;  // exit the loop
      } catch (std::exception &ex) {
        std::cout << "Ouch! That hurts, because: "
            << ex.what() << "!\n";
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I can't open the file with this loop, I always catch the exception, even if the file does exist.

Comment: @Calihog *I always catch the exception* => and what does it say?

Comment: @Thomas, well I enter the correct file name and I get "terminate called after throwing an instance of std::runtime_error what(): could not open file" and then the program crashes.

Comment: @Calihog **could not open file** doesn't mean that the file doesn't exist, you should investigate that way. Anyway, this answer is the correct pattern to use

Comment: @Thomas, well I can't understand what is going on then.. why the file cannot be opened? Do I have to throw another exception or what?

Comment: add a print of `n` in the constructor to see the string it gets. you should also gather more information about the exception

Comment: Well, it prints the correct file name... I have no idea why can't the file be opened?

Comment: Maybe you're not running the program in the same directory as the file. Try simply: `int main() { std::ifstream f("filename.txt"); if (!f.is_open()) throw 1; }` (using the correct value for filename.txt) to remove any reliance on reading the input string or looping or anything else, to check if the file can be opened at all. Learn to debug your code: isolate the problem, reduce the code to the smallest piece that still shows the problem, then fix it.

Comment: Well the problem was that I was doing the try/catch exactly on the object initialization and then after that block I was initializing the same object to use the rest of the main function. When I pasted the rest of my main function inside the `try` block it seems to work fine. But this is another question - can you do the `try/catch` block ON the initialization of the object and if GOOD - exit the block and start using the object? Isn't it pointless to put everything in `try/catch' if you're only checking for a condition which can appear in the constructor?

Comment: No, you can't do that. The object's scope ends at the end of the block where you declare it, in this case the `try` block. You can't just put the constructor in the try block, because that means the object only exists within that block. You weren't _"initializing the same object to use the rest of the main function"_, you were creating a completely different object with the same name. Please read my answer again, carefully, it is the correct way to solve your problem. I didn't just put "use obj" in the try block for a laugh, I did it because I know how C++ works.

Comment: Yes, I get that now. I appreciate your effort and time for answering my problem, you helped me understand how this work. Thank you!